# issue with starting node app with Nginx on AWS-EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy node.js app with Nginx and AWS-EC2. I use Express in my app, using express-generator. So I have the `bin\www` directory to start my app from app.js. I have installed Nginx on ubuntu (AWS-ec2). Please see my Nginx config below and part of my `bin\www` config. My question is that, to start `Node app` with Nginx on AWS Ubuntu, do I need to change the port and IP address in the `bin\www` folder? Or what other things am I missing because my app is not starting on Nginx in Ubuntu? It works well on my local machine though. I am also using my own domain in the Nginx config.

***Nginx Config***

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name partifest.com www.partifest.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
 }
}
```

***bin\www***

```
 var app = require('../app');
 var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
 var http = require('http');

 /**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

  var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
  app.set('port', port);

 / **
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

 var server = http.createServer(app);

 /**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);

 /**
  * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

 function onListening() {
   var addr = server.address();
   var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
     ? 'pipe ' + addr
     : 'port ' + addr.port;
   debug('Listening on ' + bind);
  }
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www",
  "start:dev": "node app"
},
```

Comment: If `process.env.PORT` is empty then default node js app going to run on port 3000. In nginx configuration file, you have mentioned Proxy Pass as `http://127.0.0.1:8080` so if process.env.PORT is not assigned as 8080, it will not going to work

Comment: Not what you asked for but setting up CI/CD pipelines with Elastic Beanstalk is super fast in comparison to raw EC2. Plus you will still have an option to change settings at EC2 as EB is built upon EC2.

Comment: That is what I am thinking too @Sanjiv. I just want to ask for advice before I made changes because this is my first time doing this. Also, do I need to add my `private IP address` in `bin\www` folder or just leave the `process.env.Port` like that? Thanks

Comment: @matcheek Do I need to setup Nginx if I use Elastic Beanstalk? Thanks.

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN You can configure if you want to have more control. For more info, refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html